# Is there an method to convert wifi frame to ethernet frame?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, data-link-layer

I've searched for some information about frame structure in wifi and ethernet in the Data Link layer and found out that the two frames look quite different.
I am wondering if there is some method in the router that converts wifi frame to ethernet frame in a such network where wireless network is connected to wired network, like WLAN.
Since I'm really new to this field, I may have some misunderstanding issues. Thank you.

Comment: outers strip off the frame, losing all layer-2 (data-link) information, from the packet in order to route the packet to the next interface where the router builds a new frame for the next network/interface, and the layer-2 protocol can be very different from that of the source interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting different or similar networks on the data link layer (L2) is done by a [network bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridging_(networking)) - you extract relevant data from an ingress frame (esp. source and destination MAC addresses), create a new frame for egress and copy the relevant data into it.

A bridge also examines each frame's source MAC address to learn where each node is located, so it only copies a frame to the other side when its destination is located there.

However, a *router* works on the network layer (L3): it forwards by IP destination address between IP networks/subnets. It uses data link layer (L2) encapsulation for reaching the next hop but doesn't convert anything. (It removes the encapsulating frame from a received packet, decides where to forward the packet, and then creates a new frame for that packet.)

You might be referring to a *consumer-grade Wi-Fi router* which effectively contains a NAT router, an Ethernet switch, a wireless access point (mostly bridged), DHCP and DNS servers, etc, blurring the distinction between all those functions.

Comment: A nice summary. Particularly enjoying the last paragraph.